# Is stripe send message to confirm payment?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm integrating stripe payment in my project. All payment process is done in test data, but i can't test using real card number, so i need to know that when someone enter the card number for billing, he get confirmation message in his mobile or via mail or automatically confirm payment or what happens ? anyone there to know about this.

Comment: [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/koybdf/diagram_of_how_im_using_the_stripe_api_for/)  post may help

Comment: Stripe will automatically send out emails for subscriptions based on your dashboard settings: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic